# What is the syntax for reading a slot value of an object, where that object is a variable, and inside a defrule?

Tags: clips

I've been digging through the documentation and couldn't find the solution, so forgive me if I missed this somewhere. Here's my problem: I have two instances of the PART class, part1 and part2, and the PART class has a slot named hasPort. I want a rule that matches on two part instances if the ports are connected. Each port is an instance of the PORT class that has a slot named 'connectedTo' that is used to store the connecting PORT instance.

First, my class objects:

```
(defclass PART  (is-a USER)
   (role concrete)
   (slot affectsProperty (type INSTANCE))
   (slot directlyConnected (type INSTANCE))
   (slot hasPort (type INSTANCE))
   (slot hasSensor (type INSTANCE))
   (slot hasIssue (type INSTANCE))
   (multislot secondary-types))

(defclass PORT  (is-a USER)
   (role concrete)
   (slot connectedTo (type INSTANCE))
   (multislot secondary-types))
```

I tried rules like the following:

```
(defrule rule0
   ?part1 <- (object (is-a PART) (hasPort ?port1))
   ?part2 <- (object (is-a PART) (hasPort ?port2))
   ?port1 <- (object (is-a PORT) (connectedTo ?port2))
   =>  
   ;(assert (directlyConnected ?part1 ?part2))
   (printout t "Found connected parts "
     (instance-name ?part1) " "
     (instance-name ?part2) " by ports "
     (instance-name ?port1) " "
     (instance-name ?port2)
     crlf))
```

I also tried something like the following:

```
(defrule rule0
   ?part1 <- (object (is-a PART) (hasPort ?port1))
   ?part2 <- (object (is-a PART) (hasPort ?port2))
   ?port2 <- (send ?port1 get-connectedTo)
   =>  
   ;(assert (directlyConnected ?part1 ?part2))
   (printout t "Found connected parts "
     (instance-name ?part1) " "
     (instance-name ?part2) " by ports "
     (instance-name ?port1) " "
     (instance-name ?port2)
     crlf))
```

and even something like the following:

```
(defrule rule0
   ?part1 <- (object (is-a PART) (hasPort ?port1))
   ?part2 <- (object (is-a PART) (hasPort ?port2))
   ?port3 <- (send ?port1 get-connectedTo)
   (test (eq ?port3 ?port2))
   =>  
   ;(assert (directlyConnected ?part1 ?part2))
   (printout t "Found connected parts "
     (instance-name ?part1) " "
     (instance-name ?part2) " by ports "
     (instance-name ?port1) " "
     (instance-name ?port2)
     crlf))
```

Besides what is possible, if you can share which approach is the most "clips"-natural way to write this rule, that would super appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first rule will work if you place the third pattern first so that the variable **?port1** is bound to the instance address before being referenced by the **hasPort** slot.

```
         CLIPS (6.31 6/12/19)
CLIPS> 
(defclass PART  (is-a USER)
   (role concrete)
   (slot affectsProperty (type INSTANCE))
   (slot directlyConnected (type INSTANCE))
   (slot hasPort (type INSTANCE))
   (slot hasSensor (type INSTANCE))
   (slot hasIssue (type INSTANCE))
   (multislot secondary-types))
CLIPS> 
(defclass PORT  (is-a USER)
   (role concrete)
   (slot connectedTo (type INSTANCE))
   (multislot secondary-types))
CLIPS>    
(defrule rule0
   ?port1 <- (object (is-a PORT) (connectedTo ?port2))
   ?part1 <- (object (is-a PART) (hasPort ?port1))
   ?part2 <- (object (is-a PART) (hasPort ?port2))
   =>  
   (printout t "Found connected parts "
     (instance-name ?part1) " "
     (instance-name ?part2) " by ports "
     (instance-name ?port1) " "
     (instance-name ?port2)
     crlf))
CLIPS> (make-instance port2 of PORT)
[port2]
CLIPS> (make-instance port1 of PORT (connectedTo (instance-address [port2])))
[port1]
CLIPS> (make-instance part1 of PART (hasPort (instance-address [port1])))
[part1]
CLIPS> (make-instance part2 of PART (hasPort (instance-address [port2])))
[part2]
CLIPS> (run)
Found connected parts [part1] [part2] by ports [port1] [port2]
CLIPS>
```

Rather than using instance-addresses for the slot values, you can link the instances together using the instance names together with the predefined **name** slot for each instance.

```
CLIPS> (clear)
CLIPS> 
(defclass PART  (is-a USER)
   (role concrete)
   (slot affectsProperty (type INSTANCE-NAME))
   (slot directlyConnected (type INSTANCE-NAME))
   (slot hasPort (type INSTANCE-NAME))
   (slot hasSensor (type INSTANCE-NAME))
   (slot hasIssue (type INSTANCE-NAME))
   (multislot secondary-types))
CLIPS> 
(defclass PORT  (is-a USER)
   (role concrete)
   (slot connectedTo (type INSTANCE-NAME))
   (multislot secondary-types))
CLIPS>    
(defrule rule0
   (object (is-a PART) (name ?part1) (hasPort ?port1))
   (object (is-a PART) (name ?part2) (hasPort ?port2))
   (object (is-a PORT) (name ?port1) (connectedTo ?port2))
   =>  
   (printout t "Found connected parts " ?part1 " " ?part2 
               " by ports " ?port1 " " ?port2 crlf))
CLIPS> (make-instance port1 of PORT (connectedTo [port2]))
[port1]
CLIPS> (make-instance port2 of PORT)
[port2]
CLIPS> (make-instance part1 of PART (hasPort [port1]))
[part1]
CLIPS> (make-instance part2 of PART (hasPort [port2]))
[part2]
CLIPS> (run)
Found connected parts [part1] [part2] by ports [port1] [port2]
CLIPS>
```